# How to perform binding while looping over array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array called `users`:

```
 users: [
            { 'name': 'Sam', 'level': 'level 1' },
            { 'name': 'Jhon', 'level': 'level 2'},
            { 'name': 'Doe', 'level': 'level 3'},
            { 'name': 'Jane', 'level': 'level 4'},
            { 'name': 'Smith', 'level': 'level 1'},
            { 'name': 'Roy', 'level': 'level 4'},
        ]
```

In the template i am looping and displaying `users` name like this:

```
   <div id="app">
        <div class="main-div"  v-for="user in users">
           <p>{{user.name}} <span>{{userType}}</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As shown in the array(i,e users), there is an property called `level`, Based on this property i want bind  `userType` (i,e CEO,Manager...so on)like this:

[image]

For example if the

`level 1` ====> should display 'Director', 
 `level 2` ====> should display 'Manager',..... so on.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sh29j0m7/216/)

Comment: can you explicitly state what level corresponds with what userType. In your image, `Sam` is a CEO but they're "level 1", then in your example, you state that "level 1" should be "director", so why is sam CEO and not a Director, and why is John a Director and not a Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you need methods as a helper for displaying according to its level like below ..

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [
        { 'name': 'Sam', 'level': 'level 1' },
        { 'name': 'Jhon', 'level': 'level 2'},
        { 'name': 'Doe', 'level': 'level 3'},
        { 'name': 'Jane', 'level': 'level 4'},
         { 'name': 'Smith', 'level': 'level 1'},
        { 'name': 'Roy', 'level': 'level 4'},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    userType: function(level) {
      let type = ''
      switch(level) {
        case 'level 1': type = 'CEO';break;
       case 'level 2': type = 'Director';break;
        case 'level 3': type = 'Manager';break;
        case 'level 4': type = 'employee'; break;
      }
      return type
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

span {
  fonct-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Users</h3>
  <div class="main-div" v-for="user in users">
    <p>{{user.name}} <span>{{userType(user.level)}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some array of levels mapped with userType or you can add new property in the user array.
For Ex: [{name: "XYZ", level: "level1", userType: "Director"} ...]

If you don't have this array then you need to add a condition or the function which checks and return back to you.
For Ex:

{{getUserInfo(user)}}

```
getUserInfo(user) {
  if (user.level === 'Level1') {
    return user["name"] + ' Manager'
}
```

Comment: I don't have property called `userType`, I should write conditions, I have only 4 levels.

Comment: Yeah! So based on four levels, you can create new property called userType.